# DjangoCMS: where does it search for plugins?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Cannot you tell me, where and in what order does DjangoCMS **search for plugins?**

I know that I should add them to `INSTALLED_APPS`, but what DjangoCMS does with them next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django CMS searches all `cms_plugins.py` files in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. It loads them, thus triggering all `plugin_pool.register_plugin` calls.

The relevant code is in https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/cb836a668b9e53a642a35b768bf60bda39ac03fa/cms/plugin_pool.py#L33 which triggers https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/cb836a668b9e53a642a35b768bf60bda39ac03fa/cms/utils/django_load.py#L48

While that is the preferred way of declaring plugins, note that modules imported by Django on startup can also cause plugins to be registered. Should you call `plugin_pool.register_plugin` in a `models.py` in an `INSTALLED_APP` it would also register that plugin, as the `models.py` file is automatically loaded by Django on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you mentioned `INSTALLED_APPS` and url configuration and other settings. There is an explanation for how the plugins works in this page [plugins.html](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.7/introduction/plugins.html)